Flutter In_appview errors
Flutter in_appwebview erros image I have been getting this error since i updated my macos to sequoia and xocde to latest version. I've even updated it today to RC version of xcode but still giving same error
"Specify the full class name: Instead of just calling evaluateJavaScript(:completionHandler:), use the full class name to specify which version of the method you want to use. For example, if you're using the flutter_inappwebview package, you would use WebViewController.evaluateJavaScript(:completionHandler:).
" Ive done these but same error.

I got the same issue after upgrading my macOS to 15 Sequoia along with iOS 18.
If the error persists even after changing 'Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Modules' = 'YES' in Xcode build settings, then probably the issue is with flutter_inappwebview_ios.
The Xcode 16 related issue has been fixed in the latest version of flutter_inappwebview_ios 1.1.2. You are probably running an older version of flutter_inappwebview_ios internally.
The latest version 1.1.2 required a minimum Dart SDK 3.5.0. So if you are on an older version of Dart, you could run flutter upgrade and then change the environment SDK in your pubspec.yaml to  sdk: ">=3.3.0 <4.0.0".
Clear the pod.lock and pubspec.lock file, and run flutter pub upgrade once.
It worked for me. I was using url_launcher and youtube_player_flutter which was internally using flutter_inappwebview_ios.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This issue happens in ios 18 when using flutter_inappwebview .
In the InAppWebView class Replace the following:
Before :
public override func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
After :
public override func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, completionHandler: (@MainActor (Any?, (any Error)?) -> Void)? = nil)
Also make sure to set 'Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Moduls' = 'YES'. (Targets > Runner > Build Settings > Apple Clang - Language - Modules

